# Are spark variables lazily evaluated?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark code of structure:

```
val a:RDD = readData.someOperations()
a.cache()
val b = a.someOperations1()
val c = a.someOperations2()
val d = a.someOperations3()
val e = a.someOperations4()
a.unpersist()
```

some other code in many more RDDs(other RDDs are cached in this section and other vals are evaluated).

write variable to disk(a,b,c,d,e and others)

I wanted to know if the varibales are calculated in the place they are defined or only when writing to disk. I fear if they are evaluated only while writing to disk then I will be caching many more RDDs at same time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are correct. All the `transformations` on `RDD` are `lazily evaluated` until an `action` is done like `collect()` `save()` etc

All the `transformation` operations like `map()` `reduce()` generate `physical and logical execution plans` which are performed by tracking the `parent` plans when an `action` is performed.

You can checkout [JerryLead](https://github.com/JerryLead/SparkInternals) and [JacekLaskowski](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-lineage.html) for more details.

I hope this is helpful